# Understanding Rails 3's respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, respond-with

Utilizing ActionController's new `respond_with` method...how does it determine what to render when action (save) is successful and when it's not?

I ask because I'm trying to get a scaffold generated spec (included below) to pass, if only so that I can understand it. The app is working  fine but, oddly, it appears to be rendering `/carriers` (at least that's what the browser's URL says) when a validation fails. Yet, the spec is expecting `"new"` (and so am I, for that matter) but instead is receiving `<"">`. If I change the spec to expect `""` it still fails.

When it renders `/carriers` that page shows the error_messages next to the fields that failed validation as one would expect.

Can anyone familiar with `respond_with` see what's happening here?

```
#carrier.rb
  validates :name, :presence => true 

#carriers_controller.rb
class CarriersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

...

  def new
    respond_with(@carrier = Carrier.new)
  end

  def create
     @carrier = Carrier.new(params[:carrier])
     flash[:success] = 'Carrier was successfully created.' if @carrier.save
     respond_with(@carrier) 
  end
```

Spec that's failing:

```
#carriers_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe CarriersController do

  def mock_carrier(stubs={})
    (@mock_carrier ||= mock_model(Carrier).as_null_object).tap do |carrier|
      carrier.stub(stubs) unless stubs.empty?
    end
  end


  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "re-renders the 'new' template" do
        Carrier.stub(:new) { mock_carrier(:save => false) }
        post :create, :carrier => {}
        response.should render_template("new")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

with this error:

```
  1) CarriersController POST create with invalid params re-renders the 'new' template
     Failure/Error: response.should render_template("new")
     expecting <"new"> but rendering with <"">.
     Expected block to return true value.
     # (eval):2:in `assert_block'
     # ./spec/controllers/carriers_controller_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: You are invoking `Carrier.new` both in the `#new` and the `#create` actions of your carrier controller. I guess it should be `Carrier.create(params[:carrier])` in the `def create` action method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**tl:dr**

Add an error hash to the mock:

```
Carrier.stub(:new) { mock_carrier(:save => false, 
                       :errors => { :anything => "any value (even nil)" })}
```

This will trigger the desired behavior in `respond_with`.

**What is going on here**

Add this after the `post :create`

```
response.code.should == "200"
```

It fails with `expected: "200", got: "302"`. So it is redirecting instead of rendering the new template when it shouldn't. Where is it going? Give it a path we know will fail:

```
response.should redirect_to("/")
```

Now it fails with `Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/carriers/1001>`

The spec is supposed to pass by rendering the `new` template, which is the normal course of events after the `save` on the mock Carrier object returns false. Instead `respond_with` ends up redirecting to `show_carrier_path`. Which is just plain wrong. But why?

After some digging in the source code, it seems that the controller tries to render 'carriers/create'. There is no such template, so an exception is raised. The rescue block determines the request is a POST and there is nothing in the error hash, upon which the controller redirects to the default resource, which is the mock `Carrier`.

That is puzzling, since the controller should not assume there is a valid model instance. This is a `create` after all. At this point I can only surmise that the test environment is somehow taking shortcuts.

So the workaround is to provide a fake error hash. Normally something would be in the hash after `save` fails, so that kinda makes sense.

Comment: Nicely done! Would you consider this a bug? I don't know enough about Rails yet to have an opinion. But your answer is helping me learn! Thanks again...